# Text revolving with time delay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to revolve text again and again like a quote rotator but I want to do it with different easings and animations I found a way but it is too long and once all the text ends it doesn't go again. If someone could tell me a short way it'll be appreciated

```
$('.first').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $('.second').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');}, 1500
            );
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $('.first').show().addClass('animated fadeOutUp');}, 3000
            );
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $('.second').show().addClass('animated fadeOutUp');}, 4500
            );
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $('.third').show().addClass('animated fadeInLeft');}, 6000
            );
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $('.fourth').show().addClass('animated fadeInLeft');}, 7500
            );
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $('.third').show().addClass('animated fadeOutRight');}, 9000
            );
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                $('.fourth').show().addClass('animated fadeOutRight');}, 10500
            );
```

Comment: jQuery is not well suited for complex chained animations. I'd recommend getting familiar with [GreenSock's Animation Plugin](https://greensock.com/gsap)

Comment: do you have working code with html? Cant' figure out what are you making... What means revolve? How it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set interval instead of set timeout

**Javascript**

```
var animations = ['fadeInUp', 'fadeOutUp', 'fadeInLeft', 'fadeInRight'];
$(function(){
  var i = 0;
  var timer = window.setInterval(function(){  
  $('.mydivs div').eq(i).addClass('animated').addClass(animations[i]);
  if(i++ == 3) 
    window.clearInterval(timer);
}, 1500);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mydivs">
  <div class="">first</div>
  <div class="">second</div>
  <div class="">third</div>
  <div class="">fourth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it with different animations in this case they all will have same animations

Comment: @NaizamShahzada check the updated code, you can add a diferent  animation to every div.